# Tekkit on Mac not starting up - White Screen

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos, minecraft-tekkit

Recently there was an update for mac (just a regular system update, i thought nothing of it) and immediately after the update, when i try and launch the Technic launcher and run tekkit, it lets me log in fine, but after that a white screen flashes up and the entire program crashes. No errors, no nothing, just flash of white and back to desktop.

Does anyone know of a fix for this?

Comment: We need more information. Google how to force an error log.

Comment: Does regular Minecraft work, or does it crash too?

Comment: don't use tekkit but use the [feed the beast](http://feed-the-beast.com) launcher (beta found [here](http://feed-the-beast.com/site/beta))

Comment: @ratchetfreak I notice that your solution is always to switch to FTB. why?

Comment: because I'm plugging ;) also tekkit has some shady history regarding permission to distribute the mods it contains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the Linux/JAR File version of the technic launcher then open a terminal window and cut&paste the following:

```
cd Downloads
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
java -jar technic-launcher-latest.jar
```

This will override the java version to use the older 1.6 one supplied by Apple instead of the newer 1.7 (broken) one supplied by Oracle.

Comment: You are amazing, just a note to everyone don't forget to make sure you do not have the mac version of technic downloaded afterwards or else it wont work (I had already tried just running the jar file)

Comment: Is this permanent, or do you need to do this every time?

Comment: @MarkRobinson You have to do it every time. This tells Technic to run "right now" using a specific version of Java. If you don't use this, it will keep using the system's default Java. Alternatively you can change the system's idea of the default Java using `/Applications/Utilities/Java Preferences` and you *won't* have to do this every time, but that may have unintended consequences for other Java programs you use.

Comment: If you prefer not to do it each time, you can create an "Automator" action to do it for you.  Start Automator, Choose Application, Utilities : Run Shell Script : {paste in the above code in place of 'cat'"  Save... to your Applications folder with an appropriate name.

Answer (score 2):

The java7 update of mac was causing tekkit to black out, i needed to do a complete re-install to get the thing to work.