# Tekkit crashes over and over again

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

I want to launch Tekkit on my iMac but it ends with a white screen. I tried [this solution](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92410/tekkit-on-mac-not-starting-up-white-screen) but that did not work out for me.

Perhaps because I am doing something wrong? I use Java 7 update 21. Maybe that is the problem? It works on my Macbook by the way.

Comment: Either remove all plugins and then add them back one at a time until it crashes or remove one plugin at a time until it doesn't. Then you would have found your culprit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's for modded minecraft support and we can only help with vanilla minecraft crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things to try (I have a Mac, which I barely use, but when I had a mate over, this happened):

- Try using different builds of the tekkit. This can be done by clicking the "cog" or settings symbol underneath the mod pack
- Try using java 6 instead of java 7. Also try uninstalling java7.
- Ensure that your mac is able to actually run the game. If it is an old mac, it is likely unable to run tekkit due to the amount of mods
- Buy a PC. Cheaper and less issues.

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

Go to `%appdata%` and go to `.technic` and delete it.
That's for windows and mac.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do that? What is `%appdata%` and how do I go to it? Why does this help?